# Django REST: how to prevent the value of specific model field from being serialized?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like this:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    textjson = models.TextField(default="Unassigned")
```

The field `textjson` holds JSON as string:

```
`'{"distance": 31702.1, "link": "www.strava.com/activities/2020494234", "athlete": 1, "average_speed": 6.499, "name": "Afternoon Ride", "start_date": "2018-12-16T12:13:42Z", "country": "Poland", "number": 2020494234, "date_added": "2018-12-16T20:14:01.362215Z"}`'
```

I have build an API view for this model:

```
class ListTestsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        tests = Test.objects.all()
        return tests
```

And I am serializing the model like this:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = '__all__'
```

But this makes the `jsontext` field to be serialized again when the API view is called and backslashes appear:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "textjson": "{\"distance\": 31702.1, \"link\": \"www.strava.com/activities/2020494234\", \"athlete\": 1, \"average_speed\": 6.499, \"name\": \"Afternoon Ride\", \"start_date\": \"2018-12-16T12:13:42Z\", \"country\": \"Poland\", \"number\": 2020494234, \"date_added\": \"2018-12-16T20:14:01.362215Z\"}"
    }
]
```

How do I rewrite the `TestSerializer` class to prevent only **the** **value** of `textjson` field from being serialized?

I will probably need to override the `to_representation` and `to_internal_value` methods of the field, but how?

Comment: Can you use `django.db.models.JSONField` for the model?

Comment: I believe it is Postgres only? I am using  sqlite3.

Comment: Have you tried adding `exclude = ('textjson',)` to `TestSerializer`?

Comment: This will remove the whole field. I do want to include the field in API view output, but only serialize (convert to text) its name, not value.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way. One needs to write a custom serializer field and override its `to representation` method:

```
class CustomJSONField(serializers.Field):
    """Converts only value, not name, of a field into Javascript-friendly JSON,
     not Python object or backslashed JSON. Simply avoiding the field value,
     which is a string already, being serialized again"""
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return json.loads(value)

class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    textjson = CustomJSONField()
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = '__all__'
```

And if the JSON stored in the field is a string representation of a list of dictionaries, one can do:

```
import ast

class CustomJSONField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return ast.literal_eval(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define `serializers.SerializerMethodField()`. It will return new field `textjson_original` like below:

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        textjson_original = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        @staticmethod
        def get_textjson_original(item):
            return item.textjson
        class Meta:
            model = Test
            fields = '__all__'
```